# What it the right way to be noticed when an element with specific directive attribute has been removed from DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to find a way to be noticed in case that an element added and removed from the DOM.
In case that the element removed I need to get the ng-model value of that element.

for example:
`<div tell-me-when-removed ng-model="someTitle"></div>
<a ng-click="removeTheDivAbove()"></a>`

I'm trying to get the "someTitle"

Comment: `scope.$on("$destroy", someFunction );` in the directive...

Comment: If you are concerned about the status of a DOM element in angular, then your application isn't fully "the angular way".  There is no reason that the DOM should be changing without the backing data's knowledge of the event....

Comment: Do you have a suggest for a better way?
I have form with 1000 fields. I need to know any time which of the fields are visible, and get the model names.
In case the field is removed I need to know it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
   //Your stuff here
  });
```